# How do I choose which VSO account to install Application Insights to?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-application-insights

I own one VSO account, and am a member of multiple other accounts (in a single login).  When I install Application Insights into a web project, I'm not given an option of which account to use, and it installs to the wrong account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio" 1.3.1 released 5/30/2014, allows you to select the VSO account...

I just upgraded it (from 1.3.0) and now it allows me to select which account to send insight data to.

Answer (score 1):

Changing projects in Application Insights is easy to do but hard to figure out unless you know the "trick." It's a two step process. First you need to grab three keys that are buried in the Application Insights portal, then you need to apply them to a file in your project.

To change your account or application just go to the AppInsights dashboard for the project you want to use and click the gear on the top right of the page (The URL is: `<YourVSOnlinePortalName>.visualstudio.com/_appanalytics/_admin#application=<AppInsightsProjectName>`), then click "Get configuration keys and downloads." This contains all the keys you need for the project. Copy the following three values:

`Account ID` (This is the ID of your Application Insights account.)

`Primary instrumentation key` (This identifies your data so others can't send false data to Application Insights.)

`Windows Phone 8 SDK instrumentation key` (near the bottom of the page). **Use this key no matter what kind of app your project actually is.** I.e., even if it's a Web page you will still need this value. (This is the ID for a specific application in your Application Insights account.)

Now that you have these three keys, go to your project in Visual Studio and open the  **ApplicationInsights.config** file.

Paste the Account ID into the `<AccountID>` element, the LicenseKey into the `<LicenseKey>` element and the last value, the instrumentation key, into the `<ComponentID>` element.

Fire up your app and you should start seeing data from the correct project!